# Route [calculator] not defined. Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, controller, rutas

¡Buenos días!

estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación que contiene una calculadora de margenes de venta. Esta calculadora la tengo en la primera vista, y llama a un formulario que envía al controlador del home en laravel. Por alguna razón, marca que no tengo la ruta definida cuando si la he definido en el archivo web.php y por mucho que le cambio el nombre, no funciona. He probado a generar un controlador exclusivamente para la calculadora y cambiar la ruta para que apunte a dicho controlador, pero aún así no funciona. Esto me pasa en el servidor principal, porque tengo otro servidor de desarrollo donde la ruta con esa misma función funciona sin problema. Adjunto el código de mi vista, controlador y fichero de rutas.

Vista del home:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="card" style="margin-top: 15px">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 style="margin-top:5px">Calculadora márgenes de venta</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{route('calculator')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
          @csrf
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" value="{{Session::get('calculator')}}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" step="0.0001" name="divider">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input type="submit" value="Calcular" class="btn btn-secondary">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

fichero de rutas web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('home', 'HomeController@calculator')->name('calculator');
```

función en el controlador HomeController:

```
public function calculator(Request $request){
  $request->validate([
    'number' => 'required|numeric',
    'divider' => 'required|numeric',
  ]);

  $calculator = round($request['number'] / ((100 - $request['divider']) / 100), 4);
  return redirect()->back()->with('calculator', $calculator);
}
```

Utilizo laravel 5.6. No se muy bien donde estoy fallando, espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Prueba a hacer un php artisan route:list para ver que te ha cogido bien la información que has metido en web.php

Comment: ¡Gracias por responder! He ejecutado el comando y me lista correctamente todas las rutas que tengo, excepto la que necesito de la calculadora. Simplemente no aparece, no me muestra ningún error

Comment: Pues no lo entiendo. Acabo de crearme un proyecto nuevo y he puesto las mismas rutas que tú y me las lista perfectamente

Comment: yo tampoco lo entiendo....ya te digo, en mi servidor de desarrollo no tengo problema con estas configuraciones...

Comment: Ah, si es un servidor de producción, prueba con un php artisan route:clear y luego php artisan route:list

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo y nada, me lista todas las rutas excepto la de la calculadora. No se muy bien porqué ocurre esto, voy a intentar hacerlo de otra forma, iré comentando.

Comment: Prueba si te vale con lo que dicen en esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37879020/323149

Comment: Nada, no hay suerte...el fichero de routes.php no existe dentro de la carpeta cache de bootstrap.

Comment: Estas duplicando la url `home` tienes `get('home'` y `post('home'` deberian ser distintos, solo te toma la primera

Comment: ¡Buenas Kevin! No creo que eso me cause el problema...son métodos distintos (uno get y otro post) que apuntan a diferentes funciones del controlador. También he definido dos alias para cada uno para evitar el problema, pero no me a funcionado. ¿Se te ocurre otra alternativa?

Answer (score 0):

Ya conseguí arreglar el problema. Todo venía porque en el input puse de tipo submit, de modo que lo cambié por el siguiente código:

```
<div class="col-sm-1">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <i class="fas fa-calculator"></i>
 </button>
</div>
```

Con esto la petición se enviaba a la ruta correspondiente. Quizás al no usar un botón como tal no se aplicaba el método POST. Me parece raro, porque tenía entendido que no era necesario usar el botón si tu input era de tipo submit, y me ha roto ver que en el otro servidor de pruebas funcionaba correctamente.

Espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien en el futuro. ¡Gracias a la comunidad por tratar de ayudarme!

Comment: Yo lo vería como un workaround ya que el uso de `<input type="submit">` y de `<button type="submit">` no debería de perjudicar.

Comment: Qué raro, deberían funcionar igual. Al menos ya te funciona, me alegro